# How to print concatenated iterations across a range in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Trying to make a program that outputs the sum of integers within a range of integers inclusively. This works, but I am trying to find a way for it to print out the output the way I want it to.

```
numOne = int(input('enter a number: '))
numTwo = int(input('enter a second number: '))

sum = numOne
for i in range(numOne+1, numTwo+1):
    sum += i
print('the sum of the numbers you entered inclusively is = ', sum)
```

Current output:

```
enter a number: 10
enter a second number: 15 
the sum of the numbers you entered inclusively is = 75
```

Desired output:

```
enter a number: 10
enter a second number: 15 
the sum of the numbers you entered inclusively is = 75
10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 = 75
```

I'm aware that I haven't coded for the chance that one of the numbers is negative, but that's not my concern right now. How do I get the for loop to iterate over the range and print it in a concatenated manner like the desired output? Not really needed, but curious to see how I would do it if I needed to.

Comment: this site is not a code writing service, but a learning aid site, please show your attempts to implement it

Comment: Build up the sum and the addition expression separately in the body of the loop. `sum += i` and `expr += f' + {i}'` (with a few tweaks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `str.join` and the builtin `sum` function (note that if you name a variable `sum`, it shadows that function):

```
numOne = int(input('enter a number: '))
numTwo = int(input('enter a second number: '))
nums = range(numOne, numTwo+1)
print(" + ".join(str(n) for n in nums), "=", sum(nums))
```

```
enter a number: 10
enter a second number: 15
10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 = 75
```

Comment: Thank you. Never knew I could run a for loop within a print().

Comment: It's not exactly that it's happening "inside" the `print` -- `str(n) for n in nums` is a generator expression.  That generator is the argument to `" + ".join()`.  `join()` returns a string, which is what gets passed to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

This plain loop will do.

```
for i in range(numOne, numTwo+1):
    if i != numTwo:
        print(f'{i} + ', end='')
    else:
        print(f'{i} = {sum}')
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why I would need to use {i} and {sum}?

Answer (score 0):

If the existing code must be kept the same, this will print the last line.

```
print(' + '.join([str(i) for i in range(numOne, numTwo+1)]), '=', sum)
```